# Decoding special characters with PHP

Tags: php, character-encoding, html-entities

How to convert special characters like this in PHP:
**FrÃ©dÃ©ric, BÃ©rard, JÃ©rÃ©my**

They are used in French names.

For HTML entities like **`&amp; $eacute; &egrave;`** I use:

**`html_entity_decode($myvar, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');`**

Comment: You seem to have a charset issue somewhere, that's why your words have broken characters in them. See [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: this will be your guy: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: In Portuguese I often have the same issue... have you tried using utf8_encode()/utf8_decode() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php?